# javascript append div and set its width same as an anchor text

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, width

I'm trying to create a div programmatically, append it to a parent div, and set this newly created div's width equal to the text's width present inside a `<a>...</a>`, child of the same parent div (its brother).

html:

```
<div id='div0'>
 <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
```

js/jquery:

```
        var curDiv = document.getElementById('div0');
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
        iDiv.id = 'newDivId';
        iDiv.className = 'newDivClass';
        curDiv.appendChild(iDiv);

        // the div is appended successfuly
        // next step below doesn't work

        var curTxt = $('#div0').next("a").text();
        var curWidth = curTxt.width();

        $('.newDivClass').css('width', curWidth);
```

What i get using .log is that variable `curTxt =  (empty)`, and it also returns this error: `curTxt.width is not a function`.

Comment: Have a read of the jQuery `.next()` docs: https://api.jquery.com/next/ - Next gets the next sibling, not child. Try using `.find()`

Comment: um, use inline-block and not block?

Comment: You could use a selector of `$('#div0 > a')` to access your `a` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this

```js
var curDiv = document.getElementById('div0');
var iDiv = document.createElement('div');
iDiv.id = 'newDivId';
iDiv.className = 'newDivClass';
iDiv.style.background = "red"
iDiv.style.height = "10px"
curDiv.appendChild(iDiv);

// the div is appended successfuly
// next step below doesn't work

var curWidth = $('#div0 > a').width();

console.log(curWidth)


$('.newDivClass').css('width', curWidth);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div0'>
 <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
```

your main problem is `next()` seem to search for a sibling while the link is a child

Answer (score 2):

No need for JS for this. Just set your div as `display : inline-block`.

```css
#div0 {
   border: green solid 3px;
   display : inline-block;
}

a {
   border : blue solid 3px;
   font-size : 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div id='div0'>
 <a href="#">text</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have other divs with id below div0, if i set them inline-block they move in one line, so they are set as 'block' now, cause i need em to be one over the other, and i can't use any additional divs or table cells etc., any idea? thank you

Comment: Well, now that's a different question. I answered how to have an auto-width div, now if you want one per line without changing the markup, that's another story.